# How to use the un-blocking method of MqttClient

Tags: mqtt, paho

When I try the below code to connect to the `mosquitto` broker, as you know, connecting to the broker might takes few seconds/minutes, and during that time when the button pressed to connect, it remains pressed till the connection established and when the connection established the button released back to its normal state. As far as I know, there are two way for connecting a client using `paho java API`, the `blocking method` and `unblocking method`. my question is, how to use the `unblocking method`? beow is my attempt to use the blocking method

**Code_1**:

```
//mqttFactory
public final class MQTTClientFactory {

public static MqttClient newClient(String ip, int port, String clientID) throws MqttException {

    String serverURI = formURI(ip, port);
    MqttClient client = new MqttClient(serverURI, clientID).;
    return client;
}



MqttConnectOptions opts = getClientOptions();
        client = MQTTClientFactory.newClient(broker, port, clientID);

        if (client != null) {
            System.out.println("Client is not Null");
            client.setCallback(AsynchCallBack);
            if (opts != null) {
                client.connectWithResult(opts).setActionCallback(synchCallBack);
                if (client.isConnected()) {
                    System.out.println("Client CONNECTED.");
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

what button?  establishing a connection is almost instantly.

There are asynchronous versions of mqtt.  Code samples for that.  If you want to make the synchronous non-blocking.  You could start it up in another thread.